# How to route traffic to VPN thru other linux machine

Tags: routing, gateway

In this case I have two machines RasPi and other Ubuntu server.

My RasPi (192.168.100.105) has Debian and already established UDP openvpn connection. RasPi connect to remote VPN connection 172.16.199.99.

I tried to Route this traffic using route:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.100.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.199.0    192.168.100.105  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

But unfortunately it is not working. On RasPi (192.168.100.105) I can ping 172.16.199.99 (remoute ip in openvpn) However on Ubuntu server after adding this route:

```
mainframe@server:~$ sudo route add -net 172.16.199.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.100.105 dev eth0
```

Should I install on RasPi any other package to run gateway ?

How to run route and RasPi working as a gateway for this external vpn ip (172.16.199.99)?

Comment: A block diagram of your network arrangement would help us understand what you are trying to route where.

Comment: Network is very simple. 
192.168.100.254 - Main Router (can't establish UDP ovpn connection)
192.168.100.105 - RasPi (connected VPN)
192.168.100.101 - ARM-Device-Linux- can't install openvpn
rest some other PC

Answer (score 5):

Routing is a two-way deal.

At the moment you have only specified the routing for packets to travel from your PC through the Pi and down the VPN to the destination.  At the other end of the VPN link you also need to specify routing for packets to travel down through the VPN and go via the Pi to get to your computer.

That latter would be a route something like:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.100.0   172.16.199.100  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

I.e.,:

```
route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 gw 172.16.199.100
```

(Or whatever IP address is at the Pi end of your VPN).

Your network topology looks like this (the black parts):

[image]

The VPN connection is in blue.

The routes you have, or need to have, are in green.  You already have the one on the PC - it is the *opposite* route on *server* that you need to add.

Comment: After this command - RasPi
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 gw 172.16.199.100
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

Comment: There are three computers involved in this network. Your PC, your Pi, and *the third one*. It is that third one that needs configuring with that command.

Comment: I have more devices in the network, but for this case most important are that 3 devices. That third needs to have connection to ovpn, and only raspi can establish that connection. Router should route for all devices or at least that third can route but I don't know how to make this.

Comment: You're not listening. Let me draw you a picture instead, it might help.

Comment: Thx, that's right. This is my network topology.
VPN in blue is working correct.
The problem is that I can't go from 192.168.100.101 to 172.16.199.100.

Comment: The "third" computer to which I refer is the one labelled "server". That is the one that needs configuring.

Comment: Yes. Server have this route.

Comment: I have found in vpn logs

Sat Dec 19 12:22:05 2015 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.100.200

I think that this is in ovpn server config.
This server is in other place so I can't change it so easy.
It may take few days to change it.

I just wondering if can I add to ovpn config file line to overwrite this settings to other gateway or just to add second gateway?